# How to write conditional header in ExpressionEngine for sharing meta tags

Tags: javascript, expressionengine

So I've got a fairly complex problem. Allow me to explain...

I've got an EE website where 80% of their traffic comes via social shares of their blog posts, so making sure the Twitter and Facebook meta data is perfect is key. FB and TW require the meta data that shows on a [share card](http://www.quicksprout.com/2013/03/25/social-media-meta-tags-how-to-use-open-graph-and-cards/) be placed within the  tag of your website.

There's two different times people share the site

1.) blog posts
2.) global: any other page on the site that's not a blog post

I need the variables/values inside the meta tags, inside  to change depending on whether or not the user is sharing a blog post or global page. and IF they are on a blog post, use the EE variables for that specific post.

This is my sloppy attempt at writing what I ultimately need using rough JS syntax:

```
<head>

if (is blog post) {

{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" limit="1"}

<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image"/>
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@lorem"/>
<meta name="twitter:title" content="{title}"/>
<meta name="twitter:description" content="{excerpt}"/>
<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="{blog_thumbnail}"/>

{/exp:channel:entries}

} else { 

<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image"/>
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@lorem"/>
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Lorem ipsum dolor"/>
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent tempus velit enim, sit amet pulvinar sapien blandit et. In facilisis tortor vitae quam venenatis euismod. Nunc auctor lorem porta mauris congue accumsan."/>
<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="lorem.com/_img/share.jpg"/>

}

</head>
```

I'm not sure what I should even be using for this? Is there some way to do this IF statement with EE's template code or is there some way to do this on page load with javascript and still get the EE variables?

Comment: Don't cross post across different StackExchange sites please: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/26579/how-to-enable-conditional-social-meta-information-for-blog-posts

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be as simple as using [the require_entry parameter](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#require-entry) in conjunction with [the no_results conditional].[2](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#if-no-results)

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" limit="1" require_entry="yes"}

<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image"/>
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@lorem"/>
<meta name="twitter:title" content="{title}"/>
<meta name="twitter:description" content="{excerpt}"/>
<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="{blog_thumbnail}"/>


{if no_results}

<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image"/>
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@lorem"/>
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Lorem ipsum dolor"/>
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent tempus velit enim, sit amet pulvinar sapien blandit et. In facilisis tortor vitae quam venenatis euismod. Nunc auctor lorem porta mauris congue accumsan."/>
<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="lorem.com/_img/share.jpg"/>

{/if}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```